# Django-rest-framework and authentication

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am trying to configure token authentcation on django-rest-framework.  I have added the appropriate settings, and set

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
)
```

and the authentication works perfectly from the browser client or `curl`.

However if I try to use the browseable API, I get 401 unauthorized errors.  The login page is available, but just doesn't actually seem to log me in.  If I add session authentication:

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
)
```

the browseable API works, but token requests fail with Unauthorised errors.  Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the Token in the header of each request:

The token key should be included in the Authorization HTTP header. The key should be prefixed by the string literal "Token". For ex:

```
Authorization: Token 4564b09199c62bcf94fgds46dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b
```

Comment: And how do you pass the token in each request @Anush?